How to specify DBMS_AUTO_TASK_ADMIN.ENABLE's IMMEDIATE Option?
How does one specify the IMMEDIATE option when invoking the DBMS_AUTO_TASK_ADMIN.ENABLE() subprogram?
For reference:
Oracle 19 PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference

Specifying the DEFERRED option postpones the effect of the call until
the start of the next maintenance window. If IMMEDIATE option is
specified the effect of this call is immediate – as long as there is a
currently open maintenance window.

The following is the DBMS_AUTO_TASK_ADMIN package specification notes for the subprogram.
-- Re-Enabling a Client
-- Optionally, re-enabling an Operation
-- Optionally, re-enabling a Client in a specific maintenance window
--
-- Either a specific operation or a maintenance window name, but
-- not both, may be specified.
--

PROCEDURE ENABLE (
  CLIENT_NAME      IN      VARCHAR2,  -- name of the client, as found in
                                      -- DBA_AUTOTASK_CLIENT View.
  OPERATION        IN      VARCHAR2,  -- Name of the operation as specified in
                                      -- DBA_AUTOTASK_OPERATION View
  WINDOW_NAME      IN      VARCHAR2   -- optional name of the window in
                                      -- which the client is to be enabled.
);


The code for the package spec defines constants for immediate/deferred (which aren't mentioned in the docs), and comments suggest this applies to both enable and disable. But there doesn't seem to be any further reference, so it looks like a documentation bug (going back to at least 10gR2 and still in 23ai). Perhaps an option argument was planned and never implemented, or was there but removed.
